# xdotool code works only if the program was terminated by "killall' command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, expect, xdotool

if leafpad is open.. and i close it via terminal

```
killall leafpad
```

then this xdotool code will work just fine.
it opens a file, waits 2 seconds, searches for the title, and then activates it and moves it around.

```
leafpad '/media/1/AAA'
sleep 2
a=`xdotool search --name "AAA"`
xdotool windowactivate --sync $a
xdotool windowmove --sync $a 377 153
```

but let's close leafpad manually without the 'killall leafpad' command.

now let's re-run this script.

nope, this time it is not working.

what is the solution so that this code can ALWAYS work even if leafpad was not closed via `killall` command.

what is causing this ?

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your situation, but seems like there is a different problem.

```
leafpad '/media/1/AAA'
```

This will run leafpad and then WAIT until it is closed. You have to end this line with a & to make it move on:

```
leafpad '/media/1/AAA' &
```

Also, I'd refactor your code this way:

```
leafpad '/media/1/AAA' &
sleep 2
a=$(xdotool search --name 'AAA')
xdotool windowactivate --sync "$a"
xdotool windowmove --sync "$a" 377 153
```

It is just a good habit to surround parameters with variables inside with "", also `` are sometimes confused with '' so I prefer $() instead. And there's no reason to use "" if you don't have anything expandable inside.